# Do I need to change my mapping to search with special characters in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elk

I have a cluster running and I have run into a problem involving including special characters in my search query. Now I did not setup the mapping for the index the mapping is dynamic and the analyzer is also standard. The information about the analyzer I got from the "Analyze API".

```
>  
> GET /<index>/_analyze
> {
>    "text": "some-data"
> }
```

gave me the output

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "some",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "data",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    }
  ]
}
```

my current mapping

```
message": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",
              "ignore_above": 256
            }
          }
```

Because of this output I came to the conclusion that the analyzer here is standard and the special character is not indexed. Now when I try to include special character in my search query I am not getting the desired results and when I am trying to use another analyzer in search query I am receiving null results.

Now My question is do I have a way to include special character in my search query any other way other than changing my mapping.

**EDIT:
Let me give you a example**

lets suppose I index 4 phrases in elasticsearch

> data with some-data

> data with some data

> data

> some

Now when I fire a search query like this

```
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "some-data"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I get all the 4 sentences as result. <---- This is not a desired output

The output I want is

> data with some-data

This is the only result that should come as a hit but instead I get all the sentences as hits.

Now I also fired the term query

```
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "message.keyword": {
        "value": "some-data"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This retrieved null results

The closest I came was when I fired

```
GET index/_search
    {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "multi_match": {
                "query": "some-data",
                "type": "phrase"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

Which when fired retrieved 2 results

**data with some data**

**data with some-data**

Now is there a way or a query which I can fire so that I only receive

**data with some-data**

as the result

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option is to search via [Term Level Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/term-level-queries.html) (exact term) like this: message.keyword. However, you lose the power of [Full Text Queries](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/full-text-queries.html). To use special characters in Full Text Queries, eg match query, you need to edit your mapping (you can use the whitespace analyzer) and reindex again ([Reindex API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-reindex.html) suggestion).

UPDATE:

If you can't use another analyzer, you can use the [wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-wildcard-query.html) on the keyword field. however you have to assume some problems with performance.

> Avoid beginning patterns with * or ?. This can increase the iterations
> needed to find matching terms and slow search performance.

Like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "message.keyword": {
        "value": "*some-data*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, So I have a question that while indexing elasticsearch stores the text fields as tokens and tokens are formed based on analyzer. Now the standard analyzer ignored the special character during indexing so if a value wasn't indexed then how can we perform a term level search for that. Is my assessment right here?

Comment: if you are going to use the Term query it would be something like this
{
   "query": {
     "term": {
       "term.keyword": {
         "value": "some-data"
       }
     }
   }
}
If you have any example for data and searches with special characters it would be good to better understand your scenario.
Elastic applies the same indexing analyzer at search time and theoretically would return the expected result but your scenario is different.

Comment: Hi can you see the edit I have included an example here can u plz check it out